# Convert Georeferenced imagery to vector data using python

Tags: python, imagery

Are there any opensource tools I could use to take a projected georeferenced image such as a jpg with world file, that is UTM projection such as NAD83 and convert it into distinct vector polygons using python or possibly just some software?  The end result would likely need to be a shp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Gdal_polygonize.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) that is shipped with GDAL library should do the job.

Comment: This tool is also available in QGIS.

Comment: Thank you.  I will check this out.  I would like to learn more about the using python directly with the GDAL but I'm not seeing any good beginner based tutorials on the site.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can do the conversion in [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) using GRASS tools:

> Once we have a new QGM configuration file, we can add the module to
>   the list of modules. The list is defined in
>   qgis/src/plugins/grass/config/default.qgc file. The sections in the
>   file are organized hierarchically and represented in menu as tree.
>
> Here is an example of a record for r.to.vect.line.qgm module
>
> section label="Convert raster to vector"
>          grass name="r.to.vect.line.qgm"
>
> For section/module it is possible to specify GRASS version for which
>   it is
>
> > valid using version_min/version_max attributes:
>
> version_min - minimum GRASS version for which this section/module is
>   valid version_max - maximum GRASS version for which this
>   section/module is valid General rules for new modules GRASS Tools are
>   intended mostly for beginners and not very experienced users. The
>   basic rules are:
>
> Each module should have 3 or less options; if it seems to be necessary
>   to add more options, it should be discussed beforehand Module
>   definition should be robust so that it doesn't allow a user to run a
>   module with wrong option. If there is not yet support for certain type
>   of option the module should not be added to menu

http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Adding_New_Tools_to_the_GRASS_Toolbox